# Timeseries with binary regressors

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, forecasting, binary-data

I'm trying to identify impact of some causal events on a given timeseries. However, the trouble is I only know whether the event occurred or not (binary). What kind of techniques can I use to create an effective model for this situation and use it for forecasting if I know future event dates?
Also, are there techniques which will reliably help me identify the impact of an event on the timeseries value?

Comment: Some details are not completely clear to me: a) what form of data is your time series composed of? Time stamp + numeric value? b) Do you have different event types and can you distinguish them (are they labeled)? c) Do you have time stamps for those events?

Comment: a) Yes it is.
b) Yes, the different events are named.
c) Yes, events have timestamp as well, but they don't have any values. All I know is that at which time which event occurred. So they are like an irregular binary series. In this particular case, I've 5 events so 5 such binary series and 1 temporal continuous timeseries.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you could employ e.g. [Hidden Markov Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) (HMM) or [Recurrent Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network) (RNN) for your problem. With HMM, observed states would be your events, while hidden states would reflect your time series values. With RNN, input would be your events, and the output would be your time series values.

In case you don't have a steady update frequency in your data (=uniform delays between samples), be sure to add the delay in your model (e.g. HMM can handle this well). For using binary features: you might need to use one-hot encoding (-1/1) for the RNN - but I'm not sure about this being a good choice for HMM.